# How do you call a windows .exe file from Python, enter parameters, and get a file output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, exe

Apologies in advance - I'm very new to Python and the subprocess documentation goes way over my head!

I have a windows executable that converts a proprietary file type to a Geotiff.  When I run the executable, it prompts me to put in the file name I'd like to use, and then gives me several options in turn - what would I like to do (option 6), what output file type (option 3) etc., finally ending with asking me for an output file name.  I have about 2,000 images to convert, so I'd like to automate this process.

I've tried several variations on

```
subprocess.Popen('executable, input file, arguments, outputfile')
```

or

```
prog = subprocess.call('executable',stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stederr=PIPE)
out, err = prog.communicate('filename\narguments\noutputfile')
```

or

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['executable','inputfile','arguments','outputfile')
```

Following suggestions from other questions on this site.  None of them give me errors, but they cause the file to just sit there running and doing nothing.  What commands should I use to run my executable file with the correct arguments and save the output Geotiff generated by the Windows executable?

Thanks!

Comment: A specific example would be useful. Have you read the examples to https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html ?

Comment: Yep, I've spent a good bit of time on that page but I don't understand most of what is written.  The windows executable I'm using can be downloaded at http://www.scp.byu.edu/docs/geotiff.html under the link that says "windows executable" in the second paragraph.  An example .sir file (the type I need to convert) can be downloaded at http://www.scp.byu.edu/data/Quikscat/SIRv2/qusv/Ant.html by clicking on a link in the "A Images" "SIR" column.

Comment: As an alternative, write a windows batch script (using python). For automation, have python read the input files names, create output file names and generate the batch file. Then run the batch file. Even windows batch allows <, >, and | redirection.

Comment: It occurred to me that you may be having a problem with an application  that requires the use of a terminal for input instead of standard input. If this is the case, you might try the pexpect module in python. It is another way of running programs in python.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a command-line utility can receive its parameters as command-line arguments, but sir_util2 instead reads user input from `stdin` via the C runtime function [`fscanf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb5kac8b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)<sup>1</sup>. The subprocess convenience functions `call`, `check_call`, and `check_output`don't make it easy to send input to `stdin`. Use the `Popen` class directly and then `communicate`.

I manually traced the `fscanf` calls in the source file [sir_util2.c](ftp://ftp.scp.byu.edu/software/sir_util/sir_util2.c) to come up with the following:

```
import subprocess

sir_util2_path = 'sir_util2.exe'

def sir_to_geotiff(infname, outfname, smin, smax, show_nodata):
    show_nodata = int(show_nodata)
    opt = 6 # convert to image
    fmt = 3 # GeoTIFF
    param = [infname, opt, fmt, smin, smax, show_nodata, outfname]
    cmd = [sir_util2_path]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         universal_newlines=True)
    out, err = p.communicate('\n'.join(map(str, param)))
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, 
                                            cmd, 
                                            output=(out,err))
```

I used a little test program instead of compiling the original source, so YMMV with the actual program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    float fnum;
    char str[250];

    fscanf(stdin, "%s", str);
    printf("input filename: %s\n", str);

    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &num);
    printf("menu option: %d\n", num);

    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &num);
    printf("output format: %d\n", num);

    fscanf(stdin, "%f", &fnum);
    printf("min saturation: %f\n", fnum);

    fscanf(stdin, "%f", &fnum);
    printf("max saturation: %f\n", fnum);

    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &num);
    printf("show no-data: %d\n", num);

    fscanf(stdin, "%s", str);
    printf("output filename: %s\n", str);

    return 1;  /* force error */
}
```

I forced it to exit with a non-zero return code. This lets me check the `CalledProcessError`:

```
try:
    sir_to_geotiff('example.sir', 
                   'example.tif', 
                   30.0, 
                   80.0, 
                   True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output[0])
```

Output:

```
input filename: example.sir
menu option: 6
output format: 3
min saturation: 30.000000
max saturation: 80.000000
show no-data: 1
output filename: example.tif
```

---

<sub>1. As was noted in a comment by J.F. Sebastian, a program could, but thankfully this one does not, read from the console input buffer directly via [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961), which is called by the CRT [`_getch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function.</sub>

Comment: +1 for finding out that the input is accepted via stdin (and not e.g., from console directly (`getch()`)). You may use `p.returncode` instead of `p.poll()` after `p.communicate()`. `p.args` is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use os.system. Here's an example

```
    from os import system
    system("Path\to\Application.exe input file arguments outputfile")
```

This is from Python 2.7, but should work in 3.x.